# Relevant nodes display

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7.2 core and I'd like to display similar (just by title) node links under every node. I know that there's a lots of modules to do that, but they use some kind of tags or other serious stuff and I'd like just to compare titles of nodes. If they're somehow similar put the link in the block. But... how? Or maybe I should use some module but what are these tags, how can I set them automatically to all nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I did it.
It wasn't so hard to add taxonomy tags to nodes and make them specified by nodes author. Then I used [Relevant Content module](http://drupal.org/project/relevant_content) which creates a block with nodes relevant content in it by the nodes taxonomy criteria. And it works like a charm!

Thanks to everyone who viewed this question